# TableServiceEntity Subclass with one Property to be Serialized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization, json.net, azure-table-storage

Hi I am using C# to design a class called Account, which inherits from TableServiceEntity, so I can easily store Account into an Account Table in Azure Table Storage.

I want the Account class to have the following:

```
public Account : TableServiceEntity {
      // Constructor
      public Account() { }

      // Properties
      public string Name {get; set;}
      public List<string> FriendsList{get;set;}
}
```

And for storage, I have the following:

```
  TableServiceContext.AddObject(AccountTableName, newAccount);
  TableServiceContext.SaveChanges();
```

My Questions:

1. Is there a way to serialize FriendsList and store it in the table in JSON format without creating one more string property like FriendsListSerialized? via attributes or some other mechanism?
   I prefer to store Name as its own property, so I don't want to serialize the entire object into one single string.
2. Can you use Newtonsoft.JsonConvert.SerializeObject on just one property?
3. What is the best approach to do so? :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some research and eventually found that TableServiceEntity is limited, and one cannot override the writeEntity nor readEntity methods. However, if one creates a class inherited from TableEntity class, then one can modify the writeEntity and readEntity methods with great flexibility. Specifically, one can JSON serialized a list (or any object) and then store it into the Table Storage. Changing the inheritance from TableSerivceEntity to TableEntity changes your storage method slightly. It is actually easier than I thought. Here is a very helpful page. http://gauravmantri.com/2012/11/17/storage-client-library-2-0-migrating-table-storage-code/
Hope that helps people from banging their head against using TableSerivceEntity for a long time like I did.